# Traversing nested arrays with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to rename every instance of the key "ssfollow_sinusitis" to "sinusitis" in the "ss_characteristics" array whilst still keeping the value.

I am trying to achieve this using mongoose, but having no luck as the it appears that the `$rename` operator doesn't support traversing nested arrays in MongoDB.

Below there is an example of the table I am querying, as well as an example of the method I was trying that did not work:

```
await Form.updateMany(
  { 'ss_characteristics.$.ssfollow_sinusitis': { $exists: true } },
  { $rename: { 'ss_characteristics.$.ssfollow_sinusitis': 'ss_characteristics.$.sinusitis' } }
);
```

```
const all_forms = await Form.find({})

// console.log(all_forms) will give the below.
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6413adfdea76122e6fcdefc6"),
    general_details: {
      name: 'YEYO Rae',
    },
    ss_characteristics: [
      {
        sinusitis: 'No',
        _id: new ObjectId("6450fb3d4155fbd24cb69a73")
      },
      {
        sinusitis: 'No',
        _id: new ObjectId("6450fba24155fbd24cb69ab0")
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6413adfdea76122e6fcdefc6"),
    general_details: {
      name: 'OSLAVI Hig',
    },
    ss_characteristics: [
      {
        ssfollow_sinusitis: 'No',
        _id: new ObjectId("6450fb3d4155fbd24cb69a73")
      },
      {
        ssfollow_sinusitis: 'No',
        _id: new ObjectId("6450fba24155fbd24cb69ab0")
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"mongoose": "^7.2.1",* `$rename` can not rename the field of the document in an array. You can use [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

- `$set` stage: `$set` the `ss_characteristics` documents with new documents mapped from itself. The mapping logic is: create a `sinusitis` field for each document and merge([`$mergeObjects`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/)) it with the current document(`$$this`).
- `$unset` stage: remove the outdated field `ssfollow_sinusitis` for each document in `ss_characteristics` array.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import util from 'util';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);

const modelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ss_characteristics: Array
});
const Model = mongoose.model('model', modelSchema);

(async function main() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);

    // seed
    await Model.create([
      {
        ss_characteristics: [
          { sinusitis: 'No', id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId() },
          { sinusitis: 'No', id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId() }
        ]
      },
      {
        ss_characteristics: [
          { ssfollow_sinusitis: 'No', 'test field': 'a', id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId() },
          { ssfollow_sinusitis: 'No', 'test field': 'b', id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId() }
        ]
      },
      {
        ss_characteristics: [
          { ssfollow_sinusitis: 'Yes', id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId() },
          { ssfollow_sinusitis: 'Yes', id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId() }
        ]
      }
    ])

    // test
    const updateResult = await Model.updateMany({
      'ss_characteristics': { $elemMatch: { ssfollow_sinusitis: { $exists: true } } }
    }, [
      {
        $set: {
          ss_characteristics: {
            $map: {
              input: '$ss_characteristics',
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  '$$this',
                  {
                    sinusitis: '$$this.ssfollow_sinusitis',
                    test_field: '$$this.test field'
                  }
                ],
              }
            }
          }
        },
      },
      {
        $unset: ["ss_characteristics.ssfollow_sinusitis", 'ss_characteristics.test field']
      }
    ])
    console.log('updateResult: ', util.inspect(updateResult, false, null))

    const updateDocs = await Model.find()

    console.log('updateDocs: ', util.inspect(updateDocs, false, null))

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    await Promise.all(['models'].map(c => mongoose.connection.dropCollection(c)))
    await mongoose.connection.close()
  }
})();
```

Result:

```bash
updateResult:  {
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 2,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 2
}
Mongoose: models.find({}, {})
updateDocs:  [
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("64774aa39b761d94ed079927"),
    ss_characteristics: [
      {
        id: new ObjectId("64774aa39b761d94ed079923"),
        sinusitis: 'Yes'
      },
      {
        id: new ObjectId("64774aa39b761d94ed079924"),
        sinusitis: 'Yes'
      }
    ],
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("64774aa39b761d94ed079926"),
    ss_characteristics: [
      {
        id: new ObjectId("64774aa39b761d94ed079921"),
        sinusitis: 'No',
        test_field: 'a'
      },
      {
        id: new ObjectId("64774aa39b761d94ed079922"),
        sinusitis: 'No',
        test_field: 'b'
      }
    ],
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("64774aa39b761d94ed079925"),
    ss_characteristics: [
      { sinusitis: 'No', id: new ObjectId("64774aa39b761d94ed07991f") },
      { sinusitis: 'No', id: new ObjectId("64774aa39b761d94ed079920") }
    ],
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you. However, what happens when the key has spaces in it. For example: `ss_characteristics: [{ 'test key': '10' }]`. Now, the `$mergeObjects` does not work...

Comment: @sfhasfasf If you have a new question, you can search first. If there is no such question, you can post a new one with a minimal, reproducible example and debug details.

Comment: I have now updated the question at the bottom with the new problem that has been identified.

Comment: @sfhasfasf Just do `{ test_field: '$$this.test field' }`, updated answer.